# WHERE statement in SAS EG for getting the prior month of a dataset?

Tags: sql, sas, query-builder

This is actually something I want to type into query builder in SAS EG. I am trying to filter down a data set that has dates like this:

```
SEP2021
AUG2021
JUL2021
etc…
```

I’m trying to use query builder to filter it with a WHERE statement. I want the table to have only the results dated for last month. So running it now should give SEP2021, and running it next month would give OCT2021, etc…

How can I do this with a `WHERE` statement?

Comment: Is that field a text field or a numeric field with a date format?

Comment: It is a text field

Comment: I have converted it into a date field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from KurtBremser in SAS communities, this worked for me! I did not realize what format I had converted the character value into. PROC CONTENTS revealed my values were Numeric, format DTDATE9.

Full thread here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/How-can-PROC-SQL-return-only-results-from-the-previous-month/m-p/774523

Solution below:

“
So it IS a datetime value, not a date. You need to use DATEPART to extract the date from it:

```
data have;
input date_column datetime19.;
format date_column dtdate9.;
datalines;
01sep2021:01:02:03
01oct2021:04:05:06
;

proc contents data=have;
run;

proc sql;
select *
from have
where datepart(date_column) = intnx('month',today(),-1,'b');
quit;
```

Partial result:

```
#   Variable    Typ Länge   Ausg.Format
1   date_column Num 8   DTDATE9.

date_column
01SEP2021
```

“

Answer (score 1):

Use `intnx()`. Assuming that all the dates start on the first of the month:

`where date = intnx('month', today(), -1, 'B');`

If they don't:

`where intnx('month', date, 0, 'B') = intnx('month', today(), -1, 'B');`

Comment: This looks great, but unfortunately I’m realizing the date column with SEP2021 etc as values is in character format and not date format. I’m seeing if I can convert the format in a separate program in my SAS EG run before attempting to filter it, but am struggling

Comment: Update: I have gotten the date column converted into a date format. The results now look like this and have the calendar logo above them in the output Data: 01SEP2021 01AUG2021. I am trying the first intnx function you provided and get no errors, but also no results. Is there some detail I am missing?

Comment: where date=put(intnx('month', today(), -1, 'B'), monyy5.); works for in line conversion in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INTCK function to compute the number calendaring intervals between two dates.

Example:

```
data have;
  input datestring $; datalines;
SEP2021
AUG2021
JUL2021
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select * from have
  where intck('month',input(datestring,monyy7.),today()) = 1
;
```